# Adaptive AutoSuggestBox in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have implemented an AutoSuggestBox (for search) in a UWP app as you can see on the screenshot below, and I am trying to make it adaptive but I have not yet found a way. I want it to appear like a button in NarrowViewState, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/search#Implementation

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want it to appear like a button in NarrowViewState.

I think you could achieve desired effect by using `VisualStateManager`.

For your scenario you could turn the AutoSuggestBox into a button  in `NarrowViewState` by using `MinWindowWidth` `AdaptiveTrigger`. You can try the following code or reference the [project](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SelectAllFilePicker.git) I have uploaded.

```
 <StackPanel
     x:Name="LayoutRoot"
     Height="640"
     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
     Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <AutoSuggestBox
         x:Name="SuggestBox"
         PlaceholderText="Search some info!"
         QueryIcon="AlignRight" />
     <Button x:Name="SearchBtn" Content="SearchButton">
         <Button.Flyout>
             <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                 <StackPanel>
                     <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="MiniSuggsetBox" PlaceholderText="search some info..." />
                 </StackPanel>
             </Flyout>
         </Button.Flyout>
     </Button>
     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
             <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                 <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                     <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                 </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                     <Setter Target="SuggestBox.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                     <Setter Target="SearchBtn.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                 </VisualState.Setters>
             </VisualState>
             <VisualState x:Name="Hide">
                 <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                     <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                 </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                     <Setter Target="SuggestBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                     <Setter Target="SearchBtn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                 </VisualState.Setters>
             </VisualState>
         </VisualStateGroup>
     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 </StackPanel>
```

This screenShot
[image]

Comment: Now I want the Flyout to appear in and fill the PageHeader as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820443/xaml-uwp-flyout-positioning
Please, how can I perform that?