# XAML UWP Flyout positioning

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am implementing a Flyout in a UWP app as you can see on the image below. I want the AutoSuggestBox in the Flyout to appear in (and fill) the PageHeader, but it appears below it.
[image: Screenshot]

This is my XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="searchButton" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="pageHeader">
        <Button.Content>
            <FontIcon Height="48" Width="48" Glyph="&#xE094;"/>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                    </Style>
                </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <StackPanel Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="innerSearchBox" PlaceholderText="Search" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

How can I make the AutoSugesstBox appear in and fill the PageHeader?

Comment: Do you mean like the way the search in Store app behaves?

Comment: Yes @erotavlas, exactly!

Comment: I think you should try a Popup instead, which you can put next to your button in any shape you want as a part of the layout, unlike a flyout which is sort of a tooltip or like a separate little window.

Comment: Not a bad idea @Neme, I will try a Popup.

Comment: Try setting Placement="Left" on your flyout

Comment: I have already tried @ZeaShah, but it doesn't fill the PageHeader. Any XAML to do that?

Comment: @Neme, I tried the Popup but it doesn't behave the way I want it to behave. Further help with some XAML?

Comment: What way do you want it to behave? Place it inside the header and when you want to open it, set `IsOpen` to true You might also want to set `IsLightDismissEnabled` to true if that's what you want.

Comment: I implemented my SearchBox, thank you all.

Comment: If no provided answer answers your question, write your own answer or delete the question

Answer (score 3):

Set Placement as Left for Flyout.

```
<Flyout Placement="Left">
```

If you want to make the AutoSuggestBox to cover the entire width of the application, set the width of the AutoSuggestBox to ApplicationView width.

You can do this by

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += MainPage_VisibleBoundsChanged;
    var bound = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
    innerSearchBox.Width = (int)bound.Width - 48;        //48 is the size of the button
}

private void MainPage_VisibleBoundsChanged(ApplicationView sender, object args)
{
    var bound = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
    innerSearchBox.Width = (int)bound.Width - 48;
}
```